# AI-powered Elastic search alternative, for small project?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, solr, search-engine, opensearch

I am developing a job board using NodeJs and it currently has around 1,000 items. However, I am facing an issue with deploying it on a 1GB RAM VPS as it cannot run Elastic Search on it. Therefore, I am searching for a lightweight search engine that can provide personalized search results. For instance, if a user is searching for or viewing a PHP job in New York, I will add the dataset into the search engine's history and retrain it. This way, the search engine will give a higher score to jobs based in New York. Additionally, I would like the search engine to provide recommendations for related jobs to the user.

Please help me to find one!

Comment: I don't think AI is needed to search through 1000 elements. For one, it's probably too few items to train a model and second a basic search (structured + geo) would do the job perfectly.

Comment: i want use AI-powered predict feature to show the best suggestion for candidate

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is probably a managed service from a CSP like Amazon Kendra or Azure Cognitive Search, but keep a close eye on your costs

More info:
[Amazon Kendra Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/what-is-kendra.html) | [Amazon Kendra Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/kendra/pricing/) |
[Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search) | [Azure Cognitive Search Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/)

Answer (score 0):

**Based on your requirements, there are a few search engines that could potentially meet your needs:**

1. Algolia: Algolia is a popular search-as-a-service provider that offers a lightweight search engine that can provide personalized search results. It offers features such as autocomplete, typo-tolerance, and relevance ranking. Algolia also allows you to re-rank search results based on user behavior and provides recommendations for related jobs. It is easy to integrate with NodeJs and has a generous free plan.
2. MeiliSearch: MeiliSearch is an open-source search engine that can be used to search large datasets quickly and easily. It is written in Rust, which makes it fast and efficient. MeiliSearch provides a REST API that can be used to integrate with NodeJs. It offers features such as faceting, typo-tolerance, and relevance ranking. MeiliSearch also supports custom ranking rules and can provide recommendations for related jobs.
3. Typesense: Typesense is an open-source search engine that can provide personalized search results. It is built with simplicity in mind and is easy to set up and use. Typesense provides features such as autocomplete, typo-tolerance, and relevance ranking. It also supports custom ranking rules and can provide recommendations for related jobs. Typesense can be integrated with NodeJs using its REST API.

**All three of these search engines should be able to handle your dataset and provide the features you are looking for. It's worth checking them out and comparing them to see which one suits your needs best.**